# What is the counterpart of VHDL data type integer in systemVerilog?

Tags: vhdl, system-verilog

I am trying to write a systemVerilog testbench for my VHDL designs. The problem is the data types. For instance, in VHDL I have:

```
punti_retta : out integer range 255 downto 0;
fdata_in    : in integer range 127 downto -128;
```

For the first one, I tried "integer [7:0] punti_retta" in the systemVerilog testbench; however, the tool ignored the range definition and according to the waveform it is wrong.

What and how should I define for these signals in my systemVerilog testbench? Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Verilog does not have an integer range in the same way as VHDL.

You can make an equivalent type if your integer range is a power of two like in your example:

```
punti_retta : out integer range 255 downto 0;
fdata_in    : in integer range 127 downto -128;
```

The first one is an unsigned integer of 8 bits so you can use `logic [7:0] punti_regga;`.
 <sub>Instead of `logic` you can also use `wire` or `reg`</sub>

The second one is signed integer of 8 bits so you can use `logic signed [7:0] fdata_in;`.

But VHDL also allows you to use:

```
my_counter : integer range 0 to 395;
```

There is no exact equivalent in Verilog. However when that variable is going to be synthesized, the tool must have enough bits so in hardware you get a 9 bit unsigned type. Thus the real hardware can count beyond 395!

The Verilog equivalent is `logic [8:0] my_counter ;`

Answer (score 0):

SystemVerilog does not have the concept of integer ranges, only bit-widths. You can approximate ranges using `$clog2()`.

```
bit [$clog2(255)-1:0] punti_retta;
bit signed [7:0] fdata_in;
```

Since there is no standard for crossing standard boundaries, you're going to have to look at the restrictions your tool puts on mapping port types. You might have to put the types in a common package.

BTW, the bit range in `integer [7:0]` is ignored or made an error because of a quirk in the first Verilog-XL simulator. Originally, the `integer` type was unsized and determined by the OS your simulation was executing on. They had planned to use that syntax to specify the integer size, but never got around to implementing it.